# array.slice returns 1 element instead of two

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I have an array that includes 2 strings. One in a list of numbers and another is an integer. I want to get the elements from the first string from start to the place of the integer (if the integer is 2, I want the first two numbers in the string). I've written this code, but it only returns the first character in my string. Can anyone explain why? Thanks

```js
var line = "1,2,3,4,5;2";

line = line.split(";");
console.log(line);

var reverse = line[0].slice(0, parseInt(line[1]));
console.log(reverse);
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `split` somewhere, try looking at your last two lines.

Comment: `var reverse = line[0].split(',').slice(0, parseInt(line[1]));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use split first element of `line` array then you can use join.

```
var reverse = line[0].split(',').slice(0, parseInt(line[1])).join(',');
```

```js
var line = "1,2,3,4,5;2";

line = line.split(";");
console.log(line);

var reverse = line[0].split(',').slice(0, parseInt(line[1])).join(',');
console.log(reverse);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that return what you need:

```
  var line = "1,2,3,4,5;2";

line = line.split(";");
var reverse = line[0].split(',').slice(0, parseInt(line[1])).join(',');
console.log(reverse);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace(',','')` to take only numbers from string.

```
var reverse = line[0].replace(',','').slice(0, parseInt(line[1],10));
```

```js
var line = "1,2,3,4,5;2";

line = line.split(";");
console.log(line);

var reverse = line[0].replace(',','').slice(0, parseInt(line[1],10));
console.log(reverse);
```